# cakePHP Session expiring too soon

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have set `Configure::write('Security.level', 'medium');` to low, set `Configure::write('Session.timeout', '120');` to higher numbers, and in `cake/libs/security.php` I have set the `inactiveMins()` function to the following,

```
function inactiveMins() {
    switch (Configure::read('Security.level')) {
        case 'high':
            return 10;
        break;
        case 'medium':
            return 100;
        break;
        case 'low':
        default:
            return 550;
            break;
    }
}
```

But sessions are still expiring at around 120 minutes. This is a time tracking app so I would like to have the functionality of leaving the app running in the background until needed. But the session closes too soon. Is there another way to leave the session open for hours at a time since these options aren't working?

From APP/CONFIG/CORE.PHP *********

```
/**
 * Session time out time (in minutes).
 * Actual value depends on 'Security.level' setting.
 */
    Configure::write('Session.timeout', '120');
```

Core version 1.3.4

Comment: You're probably aware of this, but it's worth mentioning that the `Configure::write('Session.timeout', '120');` uses seconds.

Comment: @MozMorris are you sure? In the comment above that line in the core.php file it says `(in minutes)`

Comment: Definitely. I'll post what I have in my core.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php.ini file was overriding cake settings. Changed `Configure::write('Session.save', 'php');` to `Configure::write('Session.save', 'cake');` in `app/config/core.php`

Answer (score 2):

This is the standard setting:

```
/**
* Session time out time (in seconds).
* Actual value depends on 'Security.level' setting.
*/
Configure::write('Session.timeout', '120');
```

I always change it to something like:

```
Configure::write('Session.timeout', 120 * 60);
```

Comment: Disclaimer: I don't always change it to that, but whenever I've needed long sessions, the above setting has served me well.

Comment: I updated my question to show what is in my core... I looked at all my other apps as well and they say the same thing. You are on 1.3?

Comment: I don't doubt you, I just asked another developer what hers says and it says seconds, so what gives? is mine in minutes or seconds?

Comment: Lolz. I'm looking at 1.3 (1.3.13 to be exact). The underlying codes sets the ini session.cookie_lifetime, which is set in seconds. Perhaps yours does a multiply by 60 in there somewhere to convert from minutes to seconds?

Comment: Still don't have my answer... Playing the waiting game now to see if it expires. I set timeout to a redic. time. Felt like I had to upvote something.